# NGINX HTTP/HTTPS Redirect Elasticsearch Breaks?

Tags: nginx

I'm working on an application that utilizes Elasticsearch on the front-end as well as prerender.io.
I've setup SSL Certs but I cannot get the http to redirect to https, when I tried to add a 301 redirect to the secure version the secure version of the site then breaks.

The redirect at the bottom for the non-www version over to the www version works fine, but if I try to add `return 301 https://www.dev.example.com$request_uri;` it seems to break the application front-end.

Here's my NGINX Config:

```
map $http_origin $cors_origin {
    default "";
     "~^https?:\/\/(www\.)?dev.example.com" "$http_origin";
}

server {
    ignore_invalid_headers off;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.dev.example.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/chain.pem;
    #return 301 https://www.dev.example.com$request_uri;
    #Potential redirection placement
    root /var/www/example/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

# Begin Prerender.io Config
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token exampletoken;
    
    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yandex|baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
    set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
    set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
    set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
    set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

    #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
    set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
    rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
    proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

    # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
    #proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9200/example$path/_search?$query_string;
    }

# end Prerender.io Config

# Various important file locations
        location ~* ^/(robots.txt|admin|api|sitemap.xml|sitemap.xml.gz) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }
        
# Favicon Location
        location /favicon.ico {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        }
        
# Robots.txt Location
        location /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    
# NGINX Log Locations
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example-error.log error;
    sendfile off;

# PHP Config - 7.3
        location ~ (/index|/calculator/.*)\.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            #fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

# This line below was disabled upon rewrite, leaving in for legacy - DR
#        location ~ /\.ht {
#                deny all;
#        }

# ElasticSearch Config
        location ~ ^/es/example(?<path>/.*)?/_(?<msearch>m?)search$ {
        
# This line below was disabled upon rewrite, leaving in for legacy - DR
#       location ~ ^/es/quirks(?<path>/.*)?/_search$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/elasticsearch.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/elasticsearch-error.log error;

        limit_except OPTIONS POST {
            allow 96.93.229.26;
            deny all;
        }
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/quirks$path/_${msearch}search?$query_string;
# This line below was disabled upon rewrite, leaving in for legacy - DR
#      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200/example$path/_search?$query_string;
       proxy_redirect off;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        }
    }
    
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl default_server http2;
    server_name dev.quirks.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.quirks.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.quirks.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.quirks.com/chain.pem;
    return 301 https://www.example.quirks.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Well - shortly after posting I figured this out by adding
" 
 if ($scheme = http) {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

 }

Comment: So you can close the question or delete it